# What the symbol of "nothing" in any programming language?

Tags: c, ruby

For example in **C**, the `NULL ('\0')` stands for "nothing". And in **mit-scheme** the `nil` or the `'()` stands for nothing. So does **Ruby** use `nil`.

So i just wonder what's the symbol or variable that stands for "nothing" in other programming languages. thx.

Comment: Note that `NULL` is not the same as `'\0'`...

Comment: Also, this isn't really an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.  If you have a question about a specific language or problem, then please ask it ;)

Comment: C is a low-level language; it does not represent abstract concepts like "nothing". All C variables have actual binary values. That value might happen to be 0, and a program might choose to interpret that as "nothing" (especially in the case of pointers), but there is nothing in the C language that actually means "nothing" the way nil does in Ruby or None in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong about C language `NULL` and `'\0'` being the same. Usually in C, `NULL` is used with pointers and `'\0'` is used with strings.

For example, The following code fragment compiles without any warning.

```
 int *p=NULL;
 char ch='\0';
```

But the following code gives you the warning "`initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast`" on compilation.

```
 int *p='\0';
 char ch=NULL;
```

So we can conclude that they are not equal and interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript: null

Python: None

It all depends from language developers preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Ruby is object. `nil` is an object and empty string `""` is also an object etc... But `""` means 0 length string and `nil` means object with no reasonable value - in some situations it really is "nothing".